# How to convert a glm::vec4<float> to a GLfloat*?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to pass a `glm::vec4<float>` to `gl::ImmediateMode::glColor4fv(GLfloat*)`:

```
std::vector<glm::vec4> colors;
colors.push_back(vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
glColor4fv(colors[0]);
```

I receive the following error message:

```
error: not matching function call to 'ImmediateMode::glColor4fv(const vec4&) const'
[...]
candidate is: [...] void gl::ImmediateMode::glColor4fv(GLfloat*) const
```

Clearly I have to convert my glm::vec4 to a GLfloat array. I read through the [GLSLanguage Specifications](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.20.8.pdf) and could not find any way to access the data directly. The following attempt works:

```
GLfloat *c = new GLfloat[4];
c[0] = colors[0].r;
c[1] = colors[0].g;
c[2] = colors[0].b;
c[3] = colors[0].a;
glColor4fv(c);
```

But I would rather use something more elegant. So is there a way to access the data array in a glm::vec4 to allow access like following?

```
glColor4fv(reinterpret_cast<GLfloat*>(colors[0].data())); 
// .data() would hand me a pointer to the float array of the vec4
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `(GLfloat*)&colors`?

Comment: As I am unaware of the way glm::vec4 is defined, I was not sure it wouldn't cause problems. The GLSL/GLM documentation seems to only talk about how to use the data types, not how they are defined.

Comment: @BWG `glColor4fv((GLfloat*)&colors[0]);` works.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I'm not sure if I got your comment right, but the `.data()` in my question is atached to one element of the vector, not the vector itself. `glm::vec4::data()` does not exist, I was just trying to point out the way I'd like to use it.

Comment: @slash: Sorry, I meant to say that in C++11, `std::vector` has a `.data (...)` member function that, for all intents and purposes, does the same thing as `&SomeVector [0]` - it gives you a pointer to a contiguous block of memory that represents the internal storage of the vector. The thing is, it is a C++11 addition to the C++ standard library, `&SomeVector [0]` is the more portable way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use [glm::value_ptr](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/api/a00183.html#gaf019636bb8bd7c9efb7c7ce3bb23bcfc). It works for both `glm::mat` and `glm::vec` and type safe.

Comment: `glm::value_ptr` returns a `const` pointer, `glColor4fv()` expects a non-`const` pointer though. But thanks for the link, I never found this documentation!

Comment: are you sure? google suggests otherwise and what kind of OpenGL library are u using.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I'm using a customized framework which seems to use specifications different from the reference documentation.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this:

```
std::vector< vec4 > colors;
colors.push_back(vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
glColor4fv( &colors[0].r );
// or this
glColor4fv( &colors[0][0] );
```